# Cant use numpy.ndarray or pandas groupby to create individual plots

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

My purpose is to plot measurement data (var1, var2,Timestamp) from each locations (ID) in a large dataset. My data:

```
ID  var1    var2    TimeStamp
AA  2       5    8/8/2010 0:00
AA  2.5     5    1/1/2010 0:00
B7  1.1     7    1/9/2010 0:00
B7  2       6    1/8/2010 0:00
B7  3       7    1/1/2010 0:00
B7  3       6    1/9/2010 0:00
C0  4       7    1/8/1900 0:00
...
```

However, as shown, the number of data (or rows) for each location ID varies (usually varies between 3-30)
To plot variables for each respective location, i'm unsure on how to proceed: 
from what I've experienced so far, something similar to the following:

```
np.array(data).reshape(500,20,15)
```

that creates a numpy ndarray by np.reshape of the original data would not let me partition the array into individual locations because of irregular shape of data. subsequently, using Pands groupby:

```
data_df.groupby('ID').plot('var1','var2')
```

Instantly plots graphs for var1, var2 for each location ID but does not give opportunity to iterate over each graph to create settings like labels / axis / limits etc. (I dont know yet how to iterate over pandas groupby objects to create and manage individual plots)

**tldr:**

Any nice way to create `np.ndarray` from irregular shaped data (as shown above) based on a criteria (for each ID)?

Any way to iterate and control over pandas `dataframe.groupby` object to plot (not just talking about summarized mean/ min /max etc) variables ?

Comment: Always provide a [mcve] of the issue, in order to make sure people can reproduce what you mean and write an answer that suits the needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `pandas` is definitely the way to go to handle this kind of data.

`groupby().plot()` returns one or several `Axes` objects. You can simply iterate over them to alter their aspect:

```
axs = data_df.groupby('ID').plot('var1','var2')
for ax in axs.values():
    ax.set_ylabel('whatever')
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks but axs is a `pandas.core.series.Series` Type, the for loop you mentioned **does not** iterate over Axes by  
`for ax in axes:
ax.set_ylabel('whatever')
...`

Comment: you're right, `axs` is of type Series, but you can still iterate over its elements. I've just confirmed that my code as written is working. If it doesn't work for you, you'll have to provide more details about the dataframe format

Comment: You could also write the loop using `iteritems()`: `for ID,ax in axs.iteritems():
    print(ID,ax)`

Comment: Youre correct! `for ID,ax in axs.iteritems(): print(ID,ax)` prints the key and axes object. But its probably my inexperience that i'm still unable to handle the axs and ax object in the for loop. or would you suggest asking a new question in matplotlib section ?
I'm trying this: 
`for ID, ax in axs:
    print(ID,ax) # just to see if the contents are okay
    ax.set_title ('title'+str(ID))
    ax.set_xlabel('label')
    ax.set_ylabel('label')`
It prints id and obj, but later says **TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable**

Comment: Thank you, i finally figured out what to do with the help of your guidance !